# Embedding Local video in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: video, windows-phone-8, embedding

I wanted to embed a locally available video inside a windows phone 8 application. Does any one have an idea how to do this?
I am pretty new to Windows Phone 8 development so would be grateful for any feedback.

Comment: What you mean locally? Have you looked/tried at/with [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.105).aspx/html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28VS.95%29.aspx) class

[Here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/playing-media-content-windows) is a tutorial.

[Here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Video_Playback_with_MediaElement_in_Windows_Phone) is another in Nokia forums.

Comment: Thanks for the same - I am using the tutorial as mentioned but I am still unable to play the video. ( I added it as a resource)

Comment: @Nakull MediaElement does not support all formats of video encoding - what is the format of the video you want to play - mp4, 3gp, mkv etc.?? also, each format supports various encoding schemes. Also, is the url/uri/location of the file correct?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!
There was some problem with the video conversion software I was using, but I was able to fix it! Thanks for your help - it was very helpful!